# Is it a good approach to use firebase once method when retrieving all posts on ionViewWillEnter?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving all posts (news) from firebase using the once method and showing it on the home tab (the first tab when the app is launched) :

```
get_all_posts(){

 this.posts = [];
 firebase.database().ref('/posts/').once('value').then(snapshot => {
   .... //rest of the code
 }
}
```

This will be fired in the ionViewWillEnter():

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   this.get_all_posts();
}
```

In this case, get_all_posts method will be fired everytime the "home" tab is pressed right? which will get all posts again from the DB or for the entire session (from opening the app till closing the app running on the phone)the news retrieved from the first time only will be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The news retrieved at first time with `once()` will fetch all the data from the reference you want to show, this will fetch the data just **once** and then detach the listener to the reference. When you press again your home button it will fetch again the data that belongs to that reference and will pull it from the database, if there is new content it will be displayed, if not, the first fetched data will be shown.

From your question

> Is it a good approach to use firebase once method when retrieving all
>   posts on ionViewWillEnter?

- Yes, in my opinion, it is a good practice to just ask for the data **once** and then display it to the user, because if you use `on()` you will be always listening for new data and your home screen might be updated with new content before the user can see the first fetched news.

Comment: I actually disagree with this as a blanket answer. It depends: if you expect users will visit the home screen multiple times in a single session of the app, doing `once()` multiple time means that you're loading the data multiple times. If your data is largely unchanged between these visit, you're reloading the data and wasting the user's bandwidth. So in that case it may be better to keep the listener active while they're navigating, so the data is still available when they revisit.

Comment: The correct answer is that it depends on the use-case and usage of your app, and those are things that only you can answer. `once` can work, so can `on`. What is better is not related to Firebase, but to your app. Study you list of use-case and (more importantly) how your users use the app (and on what sort of devices/connections).

Comment: Excellent information Frank, and yes, I forgot to write about the bandwidth usage, that's a really important topic

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the explanation, My concern was exactly what you mentioned "user's bandwidth", for example my posts are like "facebook feeds". there are many posts being updated by multiple users. so each time the home tab is pressed I would like to get all the posts (including the latest ones). I am not sure which method will reduce the consumption of user's data. after your explanation, seems like i should be using ".on" as it doesn't load the entire "posts" again every time and only look for new "posts" which reduces user's data right?

Comment: On() will fetch the data Everytime a change has been made from that reference , once will just do the same one time, and then each time you press your home button

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Firestore for a use-case like that, as it has a more intelligent client-side caching mechanism. Even when you use `get` there (its equivalent of `once`), most of the documents within the same usage session will come from the local cache. So the second `get` query would still connect to the server, but most of the resulting documents will already be in the cache.